# One ViewController, multiple tabBar items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBar with one item at the moment. For this Item I have a ViewController.

Now I would like to dynamically add more items to the tabbar which should all open the same ViewController. I will check inside the viewcontroller which button was pressed and customizie the content.

How can I add more items to the tabbar linking to the same Viewcontroller?

I tried to just add `UITabBarItem`s as a list but this does not work out.

Any advice?

Comment: In general, the tabBarController means: each tab is related to its own navigation/viewController (very rarely it is without navigationController). You might consider instantiating a new viewController of the same type if you may, and not reusing the same instance for all your tabs.

Comment: Just so I understand the question: You have a single ViewController class that you are going to use for every tab, and need it to change based on which tab it's in? Also, I presume you are using a storyboard?

Comment: @ThomasRing correct. And I want to dynamically add new tabs to my tabbar. Before runtime I don't know how many.

Comment: @dvp.petrov I tried to just dynamically add another instance of my `ViewController` but when doing so I get a nullpointer after opening the other tab, when my viewcontroller tries to access an viewelement from its view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't like your original idea of multiple SAME VC in the tabController, actually it is feasible.

```
    import UIKit

    class MyTabViewController : UIViewController{
       override var  tabBarItem: UITabBarItem!{
        get{ return  UITabBarItem.init(title: "temp", image: nil, tag: 100) }
        set{ super.tabBarItem  = newValue} }
    }

    class MyTabController: UITabBarController {

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            perform(#selector(change), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
            perform(#selector(printViewController), with: nil, afterDelay: 5.0)
        }

            @objc func printViewController(){
            print (viewControllers!)
            }

        @objc func change(){
            if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[0]{
               let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
                label.text = "testing"
                viewController.view.addSubview(label)
                setViewControllers([viewController,viewController,viewController,viewController,viewController], animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

After 5 seconds, you can see you got 5 same vc in your tabController.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subclass `UITabBarController` and use the `viewControllers` property or the `setViewController(_:animated:)` method in `viewDidLoad`. I'd recommend using a `.nib` for laying `ViewController` out, and instantiating it using `init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)`.

Instead of having the `ViewController` determine configuration based on it's `tabBarItem` property, you should have that configuration occur before setting the `viewController` property on your `UITabBarController`.

Something like so:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var controllers = [UIViewController]()

    let firstViewController = ViewController(nibName: "NIBNAME", bundle: Bundle.main)
    // Configure unique properties for firstViewController here, including
    // the tabBarItem.
    controllers.append(firstViewController)

    // Configure the rest of the ViewControllers with unique properties and add them to controllers

    setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
  }
}
```

Also, note that if you have more than 5 controllers you will need to utilize the `moreNavigationController` property in your UITabBarController subclass.

I recommend you [read the documentation for UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller) to get an idea on how to do all of this.